Where (in what file and directory) is the path to the Java JDK stored in Matlab?
I'm trying to locate the file in the Matlab installation or per-user configuration in which the path to the Java JDK is stored.
I tried changing the JDK path via jenv and then looking for a recently-modified file (via find . -type f -mtime -1) but the only files found by that test do not seem to contain the Java JDK path.
The bigger picture is that I am running Matlab in a Docker container (see this web page about that) and I am trying to create a persistent configuration for the Java JDK. I can change the JDK location via jenv when Matlab is running in a Docker container, but that change is forgotten after exiting and relaunching Matlab.

This is explained in this documentation page. In short, the function prefdir returns the path to where preferences are stored.
In Linux this is ~/.matlab/<release>. It being a hidden directory explains why your find command didn’t find it.
If you fail to find the right file where this configuration is stored in, you can always add your jenv command to your startup.m file. [Doesn't work in this case because changing the Java environment used requires restarting MATLAB.]

In the preferences directory, there's a file called matlab.mlsettings. This is a ZIP file. Once unzipped, you'll find a JSON file at fsroot/settingstree/matlab/external/interfaces/java/maca64/settings.json (the maca64 part is for macOS, on Linux this will likely be glnxa64 instead of maca64). This JSON file has a bit that reads
"name":"JrePath","value":"<path>"

My guess is that you can edit the path there, zip up the directory again, and replace the original matlab.mlsettings file.

Hmm, after jenv /path/to/jdk, I see three files in $HOME/.matlab/R2023a which have changed, namely matlab.mlsettings, history.m, and toolbox_cache-9.14.0-2485697813-glnxa64.xml. Now history.m is just the history file and toolbox_cache-9.14.0-2485697813-glnxa64.xml appears to be lists of files for each toolbox. The other one matlab.mlsettings might contain configuration data, but it is binary data, so I can't readily edit it to put in the path I need.

About a jenv command in startup.m, the difficulty I see is that Matlab always says to restart in order for the changes to take effect, so just putting jenv won't make the change available in that same session. (As I was saying, the Docker image seems to make a clean start each time, so it doesn't know about changes in a previous session.)

@robert oh, yeah, I didn’t think of the need to restart after setting the Java environment.

@RobertDodier I poked around a bit, the binary file is a ZIP file. I've updated the answer.

OK, great, that makes sense. I will try that.
